# Non Latin characters shows as '?'

Tags: java, java-8, properties

I have a property like `name.label=名`

My java code is like

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path)) {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    properties.load(reader);
    System.out.println("Name label: " + properties.getProperty("name.label"));
    reader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't find properties file. ", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't close input stream. ", e);
}
```

but it prints

> Name label: ?

I am using java 8.

Comment: You need to replace with unicode.try putting `\u540D` this in properties file and check

Comment: It will turn every thing into non-latin characters.

Comment: Try `System.out.println("Name label: "+(int)properties.getProperty("name.label").charAt(0));` Does it really print `63` for `?` or the intended unicode number? In the latter case, it’s just an issue of your console not being able to show the character. By the way, you should add the `Reader` declaration to the surrounding `try()` instead of closing it manually.

Comment: @Holger It prints `63`. I have also debug this and it also shows `?`

Comment: Then, you may check whether the input file truly is `UTF-8` encoded. E.g. when you use `Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));`, you will get a reader which will throw an exception on malformed input, rather than replacing it with `?`.

Comment: @Holger yes. file is saved with `ANSI` encoding. Changing it fixed the issue. Can you put an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A replacement character may indicate that the file is not encoded with the specified `CharSet`.

Depending on how you construct the reader, you’ll get different default behavior regarding malformed input.

When you use

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try(FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

    properties.load(reader);
    System.out.println("Name label: " + properties.getProperty("name.label"));
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't find properties file. ", e);
} catch(IOException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't read properties file. ", e);
}
```

you get a `Reader` with a `CharsetDecoder` configured to replace invalid input. In contrast, when you use

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try(Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path))) { // default to UTF-8
    properties.load(reader);
    System.out.println("Name label: " + properties.getProperty("name.label"));
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't find properties file. ", e);
} catch(IOException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't read properties file. ", e);
}
```

the `CharsetDecoder` will be configured to throw an exception on malformed input.

For completeness, here’s how you can configure the behavior if neither default fits your needs:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
CharsetDecoder dec = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    .replaceWith("!");
try(FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, dec)) {

    properties.load(reader);
    System.out.println("Name label: " + properties.getProperty("name.label"));
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't find properties file. ", e);
} catch(IOException e) {
    log.debug("Couldn't read properties file. ", e);
}
```

See also [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and [`CodingErrorAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html).